# Decimal arithmetic in shell shows as command not found

Tags: shell

My intention is to reduce or increase brightness levels using code

The following is my code

```
BRIGHTNESS=`xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '`
z=$($BRIGHTNESS-0.1)
echo "$z"
```

I get the error `adjust_brightness.sh: line 4: 1.0-0.1: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(...)` is a command substitution. Command substitution executes the commands inside it. Here it tries to execute `1.0-0.1` as a command.

The `$((...))` does arithmetic expansion, note the double braces.

While the following will trigger arithmetic expansion:

```
z=$(($brightness-0.1))
```

No, shell does not support floating point arithmetic, only whole numbers. Research other questions on this site how to do floating point arithmetic in shell. Because arithmetic expansion expands also variables, you can remove the `$` from inside. For example pipe the string to be calculated to `bc` (`<<<` is a here string):

```
z=$(bc <<<"$brightness - 0.1")
```

Notes:

- And while were at it, do **not** use backticks `...` at all. Use `$(...)` instead. `brightness=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' ')`
- UPPER CASE VARIABLES are by convention reserved for exported variables, like `IFS`, `LINES`, `COLUMNS` etc. Use lower case variables in your scripts.

Comment: *Some* shells don't support floating-point arithmetic; `zsh` is a notable exception.